# JDBC Batch Insert of Nested Records

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, nested, batch-processing

I'm wondering if there's an accepted pattern for performing a batch insert of nested records in JDBC.  Specifically, I have an XML file that contains three types: Wrapper, A, and B.  Wrapper only ever occurs once in the XML file and has a one-to-many relationship with A.  As you may have guessed, A also has a one-to-many relationship with B such that an example file looks like

```
<Wrapper>
  <A>
    <B></B>
    <B></B>
    <B></B>
  </A>
  <A>
    <B></B>
    <B></B>
    <B></B>
  </A>
  <A>
    <B></B>
    <B></B>
    <B></B>
  </A>
</Wrapper>
```

Do I first iterate over the A elements in order to perform a batch insert of A records and then iterate again over the A elements and each B element in order to perform a subsequent batch insert of B records?  Or is there a way that I can do this so that only one iteration and one batch insert are necessary?

Comment: As I understood it you are going to need the generated id of A to store B. Then why not insert A without a batch and insert B within a batch? That will give you a single iteration over the XML. But in the end it goes all down to the size of the XML, you db performance, the objects sizes etc... So hard to give concrete advice from here.

Comment: The XML file is big and can have a large number of A elements within the Wrapper elements or a large number of B elements within an A element.

Comment: I think with 2 passes as you're doing the best way IMO

Comment: Easy to implement, easy to extend (one more level, one more pass) and performs well too. For me, it is eligible to become a pattern itself :-)